# R gif with function

Tags: r, gif

I am trying to make a *gif* out of an R-Script using a function to generate the images.

I have a function that given some information creates a Map with dots on it. 
I use this function on a Vector obtaining a series of different images, and I would like to put them together in a gif. It looks more or less like that:

```
createMap <- function(my_variable){
my_map <- a_map() + geom_point() # some variable missing

png(filename = paste(aDate, ".png", sep = ""), width = 3149, height = 2183, units = "px")
plot(mw_map)
dev.off()
    }
```

ImageMagick is installed on my pc and the conversion file "converter.exe" also. Later I try to generate the gif using

```
   saveGIF({

lapply(my_vector, createMap)

  }, movie.name = "MY_GIF.gif")
```

but I get an error message:

```
> convert: improper image header `Rplot1.png' @
> error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/4362. convert: no images defined `MY_GIF.gif'
> @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3254.
```

`an error occurred in the conversion...`

does anybody know what I did wrong?

Comment: Looking at `?saveGIF`, it seems like if you are using an expression, it expects the expression to create the plots in the graphics device, not on disk. On the other hand, if you have a function that produces PNGs that you want stitched together, create those PNG files first and then provide the names using the `img.name` argument.

Comment: that's right, I tried it before to plot the maps on the graphic device and it actually worked, but I couldn't set dimensions and resolution. Do you know how to set it without saving the plot on disk? 
I don't understand what do you mean with "provide the names"

Comment: The `img.name` documentation says *"file name of the sequence of images (‘pure’ name; without any format or extension)"*, so if you already have files `g1.png`, `g2.png`, `g3.png` that you want stitched together, you would use `saveGIF(img.name = c("g1", "g2", "g3"), move.name = "my_gif.gif")`. I think.

Comment: There's a JSS paper about how to use it - following an example there might be the easiest: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v053i01

Answer (score 0):

After creating the map png files. Use the below code. You don't need ImageMagick is installed on PC.

```
    library(magick)

    png.files <- sprintf("Rplot%02d.png", 1:10) #Mention the number of files to be read
GIF.convert <- function(x, output = "animation.gif")#Create a function to read, animate and convert the files to gif
        {
        image_read(x) %>%
        image_animate(fps = 1) %>%
        image_write(output)
        }

        GIF.convert(png.files)
```

For more details check this link: [Link](https://gist.github.com/jeroen/1af6098a7d24045ec2b08f7aa795c55a)